# Apply a function within list-column to another column (compare to reference ecdf by group)

Tags: r, purrr

I have a dataset that is organized by groups (site) and has baseline observations (trt == 0) and observations collected from a modified environment (trt == 1, although it's not experimental data which is why I'm doing this). For the trt == 1 observations, I would like to calculate the quantile of each observation within the baseline ecdf for that group (i.e. site). My instinct was to use map2_dbl() but the ecdf to compare to is within the list-column itself, not external to the data. I'm struggling to get the correct syntax (in the R tidyverse).

```
df <- tibble(site = rep(letters[1:4], length.out = 2000),
             trt = rep(c(0, 1), each = 1000),
             value = c(rnorm(n = 1000), rnorm(.1, n = 1000)))

# calculate ecdf for baseline:
baseline <- df %>%
  filter(trt == 0) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  summarize(ecdf0 = list(ecdf(value)))

# compare each trt = 1 observation to ecdf for that site:
trtQuantile <- df %>%
  filter(trt == 1) %>%
  inner_join(baseline) 
# what would be next line is where I'm struggling to get the correct map syntax
head(trtQuantile)

# for the first row I am aiming for the result given by:
trtQuantile$ecdf0[[1]](trtQuantile$value[[1]])
```

Any advice from the purrr masters is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map2_dbl` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

trtQuantile %>% mutate(out = map2_dbl(ecdf0, value, ~.x(.y)))
```

Or `mapply` in base R :

```
trtQuantile$out <- mapply(function(x, y) x(y),trtQuantile$ecdf0,trtQuantile$value)
```